# How To Redeploy Exiting Web Application Using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed my Web App using Firebase.I then changed my application code and redeployed. I still see the old web app and not the revision.

Comment: Hello, you should share much more info than what we see in your question in order for us to help you. Firebase project structure, command used to deploy, etc..

Comment: @Meet When you provide the `firebase.json` file as well as the commands you use to deploy, please edit the question instead of pasting them in the comments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.